# СSS фон на всю высоту

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Есть 3 блока , в каждом имется фон подложка в виде отдельно div c классом card-cell-bg. Во всех браузерах, кроме IE11 этот фон тянется на всю высоту
Как быть с IE?

Это появляется из-за свойство table-cell. Есть вариант назначить фон для блоков table-cell - но вылезает другая проблема - это отступы между ячейками table-cell

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39o7x7nk/7/)

**html**

```
<div class="card-table">
            <div class="card-row">
                <div class="card-cell">
                    <div class="card-cell-bg"></div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x160/b91c3d/ffffff" alt="" class="src">
                    <div class="card-cell-body">
                        <a href="" class="link-details">«Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a>
                        <p class="font-small card-cell-text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-cell">
                    <div class="card-cell-bg"></div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x160/b91c3d/ffffff" alt="" class="src">
                    <div class="card-cell-body">
                        <a href="" class="link-details">«Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a>
                        <p class="font-small card-cell-text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  "</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-cell">
                    <div class="card-cell-bg"></div>
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x160/b91c3d/ffffff" alt="" class="src">
                    <div class="card-cell-body">
                        <a href="" class="link-details">«Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a>
                        <p class="font-small card-cell-text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**scss**

```
.card-table {
    display: table;

    .card-row {
        display: table-row;
    }

    .card-cell-bg {
        position: absolute;
        width: 220px;
        top: 0;
        left: 20px;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .card-cell {
        position: relative;
        display: table-cell;
        width: 260px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;

        &:first-child, &:last-child {
            width: 220px;
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-right: 0;

            .card-cell-bg {
                @extend .card-cell-bg;
                left: 0;
            }
        }
    }

    .card-cell-body {
        padding: 15px 20px 25px 20px;
    }

    .card-cell-text {
        line-height: 15px;
        margin-top: 12px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема осталась в ie со времён спецификации [css 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout), где нельзя было назначать процентную высоту элемента внутри ячейки.

Делай этому бэкграунду 9999 пикселей высоты и обрезай лишки при помощи overflow: hidden

```css
.card-table {
  width: 700px;
  display: table;
}
.card-table .card-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.card-table .card-cell-bg,
.card-table .card-cell:first-child .card-cell-bg,
.card-table .card-cell:last-child .card-cell-bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  height: 9999px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.card-table .card-cell {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 260px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card-table .card-cell:first-child,
.card-table .card-cell:last-child {
  width: 220px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.card-table .card-cell:first-child .card-cell-bg,
.card-table .card-cell:last-child .card-cell-bg {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-table">
  <div class="card-row">
    <div class="card-cell">
      <div class="card-cell-bg"></div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/220x160/b91c3d/ffffff" alt="" class="src">
      <div class="card-cell-body">
        <a href="" class="link-details">«Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a>
        <p class="font-small card-cell-text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-cell">
      <div class="card-cell-bg"></div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/220x160/b91c3d/ffffff" alt="" class="src">
      <div class="card-cell-body">
        <a href="" class="link-details">«Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a>
        <p class="font-small card-cell-text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, "</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-cell">
      <div class="card-cell-bg"></div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/220x160/b91c3d/ffffff" alt="" class="src">
      <div class="card-cell-body">
        <a href="" class="link-details">«Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</a>
        <p class="font-small card-cell-text">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
          irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```